# How to pass variables into split()?

Tags: r, split

I want to run `split()` in a for loop, but when I pass it variable text, it just creates a new data.frame containing the text. The idea here is to split `CMPD_DF_1`, `CMPD_DF_2`, etc. based on `CMPD_DF_1[5]`, `CMPD_DF_2[5]`, etc. How do I pass in the data.frame and not a string?

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  split(paste("CMPD_DF", i, sep = "_"), 
        paste(paste("CMPD_DF", i, sep = "_"), "[5]", sep=""))
}
```

Comment: I don't completely understand what you're trying to do. Are you sure you're not confusing `split` with `strsplit`?

Comment: split() will break the data.frame into smaller data frames based on the contents of one column. I am trying to pass in data frames one at a time to be "split" into their smaller parts.
`split(d.f, d.f[5])` will make as many data frames as there are unique values in d.f[5], each one containing the rows associated with that value in [5]. Sorry, I am having trouble explaining.

Comment: Sorry for the initial confusion, I think I have something workable for you below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you're not passing a data.frame to `split`.  You're passing a character vector that contains a string with the name of your data.frame.  Something like this should work, but it's not very R-like.  @joran's answer is preferable.

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  dfname <- paste("CMPD_DF", i, sep = "_")
  split(get(dfname), get(dfname)[5])
}
```

Comment: Joran's answer is fine, but I still have the problem of creating the list in a for loop. The number of data frames will be different each time, so that is why I need the loop. I can't hard code the list `l <- list(d1,d2)`. This solution will work. Thanks.

Comment: @James - Never feel bad about accepting the answer you found most useful. I would note, though, that if you're hard coding the data frames, and there are a different number of them in different cases, how would you know how long to make your for loop in each case w/out hard coding that too? It's almost always better practice (and easier) to keep related structures in a single object, like a list.

Comment: I am using a naming convention internally so that I can count them. `for(i in 1:length(grep("CMPD_DF_", ls(), fixed=TRUE)))` I am an R noob, so I am probably still thinking more procedurally than I need to. I would love to leave these groups all in one d.f and work on them there. More reading ahead of me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the initial confusion. You can put your data frames in a list and then use `lapply`. This assumes the column you are splitting on is the same in each data frame. I'll update with a more general solution...

```
d1 <- data.frame(x =1:10, y = rep(letters[1:2], each = 5))
d2  <-  d1

l <- list(d1,d2)
myFun <- function(x){
  return(split(x,x[,2]))
}
lapply(l,myFun)
```

And here's a way to do this using `mapply` that will allow for different splitting columns in each data frame. You just pre-specify the columns in a separate list and pass them to `mapply`:

```
l <- list(d1,d2)
splitColumns <- list("y","y")
myFun2 <- function(x,col){
  return(split(x,x[,col]))
}
mapply(myFun2,l,splitColumns,SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```